# Docker -v paramter limited in size

Tags: docker

I'm trying to mount a directory from my host to my container with

> docker ... -v /host/path/to/dir:/container/dir ...

On the host /host/path/to/dir has ~500GB available space, in the container the 'mount' point has 20GB

Why is this, and how can I fix it? I want to expose the full 500GB

Comment: Which storage driver are you using? Can you run `docker info`?

Comment: What system are you running on; are you on Windows or OS X, and using Boot2Docker?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this behavior locally.  I have a `/home` filesystem on my host:

```
/dev/dm-28                        118G  104G  9.0G  93% /home
```

If I start a docker container like this:

```
$ docker run -it -v /home:/home fedora bash
```

I see that space available inside the container:

```
[root@08671029e0ae /]# df -h /home
Filesystem                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/luks-8245e7a1-dd00-48aa-9f24-9cbe887d114a  118G  104G  9.0G  93% /home
```

If you're not seeing this behavior, can you update your question with specific output of `df` both inside and outside the container, and the specific `docker run` command you're using.